# material-ui: How to always show nestedList toggle, regardless if there are no nested items

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a Material ui  that I am using as a tree to navigate my store's entities.

I want the nestedItems to load as and when required, and am using the onNestedListToggle function callback to fetch the items from the server to populate the nested items.
Unfortunately, the api doesnt (obviously at least) expose a prop to configure the listitem to show the nestedlistitem toggle regardless of whether or not there are any nestedItems. This means there is no button/toggle available to me on initial render that will allow the user to load the nested items on expand.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you saying the toggle arrow doesn't appear when you have no nested items to view (but will once the request happens) ? if thats the case you could just populate the nestedItems array with a single item when there isn't anything to view yet. Maybe a div with the text `Loading...` for instance.

Comment: Please Provide a [MCVE]